# MySql - Way to update portion of a string?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-update

I'm looking for a way to update just a portion of a string via MySQL query.

For example, if I have 10 records all containing `string` as part of the field value, is there a way to change `string` to `anothervalue` for each row via one query?

I.e. for the following:

Change `something/string`, `something/stringlookhere`,  `something/string/etcetera` to
`something/anothervalue`, `something/anothervaluelookhere`, `something/string/etcetera`

Answer (score 261, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
UPDATE table
SET field = REPLACE(field, 'string', 'anothervalue')
WHERE field LIKE '%string%';
```

Answer (score 27):

```
UPDATE `table` SET `field` = REPLACE(`field`, 'string', 'anothervalue')
```

Answer (score 14):

Use the `LIKE` operator to find the rows that you care about and update them using the `REPLACE` function.

For example:

```
UPDATE table_name SET field_name = REPLACE(field_name,'search','replace') WHERE field_name LIKE '%some_value%'
```