# sql query to strip random characters

Tags: php, mysql

in my database i have many books which i have information of, however the isbn-10 entries of these books are messed up because i forget to strip the "-" from them when they were first inputted into the database, so for example in the field `description` i may have an entry like this,

```
ISBN10: 0-470-945-176
by Paul D. Kimmel
Publisher: John Wiley &amp; Sons
Copyright year: © 2011
```

however most of my data is like this

```
ISBN10: 0470945176
by Paul D. Kimmel
Publisher: John Wiley &amp; Sons
Copyright year: © 2011
```

what mysql query should i use to strip the "-" from the `description` so that my data is properly formatted like the 2nd example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MySQL [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) string function.

```
UPDATE books SET description = REPLACE(description, '-', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

[Command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html):

```
UPDATE TableName SET `description` = REPLACE(`description`, '-', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into a replace function and possibly mySql's regex functionality, depending if other parts of the description contain "-" characters.

[MySQL string replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956993/mysql-string-replace)
http://www.regular-expressions.info/mysql.html