# Replace single letter in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, regex, replace

How I can replace a single letter in any collumn / any row in selected mysql table? I found a solution but it works only with whole words. I has a problem with correct encoding, now I must fix those records. Replace in PHP will not work, it's over 50k records.

For example:

`�wierk` -> `Świerk`

or

`Wizyt�wka` -> `wizytówka`

Comment: Take a look at
 [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956993/mysql-string-replace)

Comment: What solution did you come up with only works with whole words?

Comment: Mysql replace, any regexp wont work with this function. I can replace only whole words. It's hard to select letter that is marked as --> �. I don't know is is "ą", "ę" or other letter. You know what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can effectively replace a certain character this way :

```sql
update <table> set <field> = replace(<field>, CHAR(<old ascii>), CHAR(<new ascii>))
```

It works also with special characters like VT vertical tab, ascii 21 and so on.

---

To get the ASCII value you can use [ord()](https://www.php.net/ord)

```php
$ascii = ord($char);
```

But first of all, I would ensure that it actually *is* wrong data you have in your table, and not just wrong encoding you get when you query.

have you tried `mysql_set_charset('utf8')` *before* you run your query?

Comment: Ok thank You, but is there a method to recognize which letter is hidding under �?

Comment: @user3253314 - Use the ASCII function after choosing the character via SUBSTRING

Comment: @AgRizzo, yes - even better

Comment: Yes, I changed charset after I inserted records. By bad :( Now I must fix them. Your solution is this what I need

Answer (score 0):

well you can iterate through each letter of the string if its a string

```
$myString = "hello";

$length = strlen($myString);

for($a = 0; $a<=$length-1; $a++){
    echo $myString[$a]."<br>";
    if($mystring[$a] == '�'){
      /* do something  */
    }
}
```

there are other ways too like `explode()`

Answer (score 0):

use `LOCATE()` to locate letter and `SUBSTRING()` and `CONCAT()` to fix it.

```
SELECT Content,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Content,1,LOCATE('�', Content)-1),"Ś",SUBSTRING(Content,LOCATE('�', Content)+1)) FROM Table
```