# how to change column value on a cetain condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

i am using mysql database. in table i am saving files name with extension. my files extension is .flv but i want to change file extension from .flv to .mp4. is there any way to achive this in mysql workbench. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL string replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956993/mysql-string-replace)

Comment: there is hundreds of records there. and i want to change all.

Comment: That's what that answer does, in your case it would be something like update myTable replace .flv with .mp4 where file name like '%.flv'. How many it does depends on how restrictive the where clause is, nothmng to do with replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
update tablename set colname = replace(colname,'.flv','.mp4');
```