# MYSQL Update part of String if that piece is not in the string and do nothing if it's there

Tags: mysql, string, replace, edit

I have got a string like this

> ****1****2****22****111****3****34****21****33****23****213****213****222****55****152****36

Let's say I have a new number to add to this string like `****44`,

I want to `UPDATE` the string and add that number `****44` Only if it is not already in there.

**If a number is already there** i.e. Suppose I want to add `****22`, the `UPDATE` should not happen because `****22` is already in the string.....

However, if I have `****22222`, the `UPDATE` should Proceed.

How can this possibly be done:

So far I have this great thoughts from this SO Link: [MySQL string replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956993/mysql-string-replace)

However, using this code *(got from the SO Link as the Accepted answer there):*

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, 'articles/updates/', 'articles/news/')
WHERE your_field LIKE '%articles/updates/%'
```

I dont get how **the checking of if the piece already exists** will be done cause, this seems to be a direct change from one string to another.

Any Suggestion is honored.

Comment: Where in the string do you want to add the new piece of data? The query in your post replaces existing values - it doesn't add new.

Comment: The new `piece` can be added anywhere in the string... Thank you!

Comment: I'm curious, why are you storing IDs like this?

Comment: These `Ids` are `Questions` of Give `Subjects`. Each `Subject` has like 30`Questions`. The `questions` are stored in that manner to be dealt with as an `Array` when we `Split(****)` for each `Subjects`. So suppose I had 20 `Subjects` and 30`Qstn/Subjcts` We avoided having a new *(third)* `Table` for their relationship. It might no be a good practice but Works Faster so far.

Comment: yes, it's not a good pratice. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the column you want to add data to is of a character type this should work:

```
update your_table
set your_column = concat(your_column, '****22')
where your_column not like '%****22*%' 
  and your_column not like '%****22';
```

The first where condition filters out cases where`****22`would match a longer similar sequence like`****222`in the middle of the string by checking that the match is followed by a`*`and the second condition filters out matching rows that end with`****22`and thus are not followed by any`*`.

This will append`****22`at the end of`your_column`

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01959d)

Comment: this will not work for the case that the user show. `****22` and existant `****2222`

Comment: Please UpVote if you think the Question is UpVote worth... thx

Answer (score 0):

The following statement will update all rows and tack on a '22' to the end of 'myval' if it doesn't have '22' in the value somewhere. If you're literally dealing with *** characters, you have to escape them in the regexp.

```
update foo set myval= if(myval regexp '22',myval,concat(myval,'22'));
```

Comment: Thanx though i get ERROR: `#1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp`

Comment: Yeah, you have to escape the *** characters. That's why my example doesn't use em. I actually ran this query on a temp table- the first time, it tacks on '22' to all rows that don't already have '22', the second time, it affects no rows, because it already updated them.

Comment: What I wrote: `UPDATE `all_sets_subjects` SET `all_questions_ids` = 
 if(`all_questions_ids` `regexp` `'****22'`,`all_questions_ids`,`concat(myval,'22')``);`

Comment: Give this a shot-- UPDATE all_sets_subjects` SET all_questions_ids = if(all_questions_ids regexp '\\*\\*\\*\\*22',all_questions_ids,concat(myval,'****22')``)  -- err... SO seems to be munging slashes.. there should be two slashes per asterisk in the regexp.