# MySQL update Drupal nodes uploaded documents url

Tags: drupal-7, sql-update, document-body

**Can anyone advice on how I can mass update document urls in node body content?**

I am in the process of migrating a just over a thousand pages into Drupal using the migrate module.

The pages are successfully migrating but they also have PDF documents uploaded into the body field of a lot of the nodes. Those pdf links are now broken because the pdf documents are uploaded into a **migration/intranet/files/** directory as opposed to **files**.

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956993/mysql-string-replace) example, I tried the following directly approach to update a sample body field:

```
UPDATE field_data_body SET body_value = REPLACE( body_value, '<a href=\"', '<a href=\"/migration/intranet/files/') where entity_id=20916;
```

My update works but I get the following path as a result:

```
http://*.*.*.*/intranet/migration/intranet/files/migration/intranet/files//migration/intranet/files///migration/intranet/files/migration/intranet/files/intranet/migration/intranet/filess1_2015_-_iworld_release_6.12.pdf
```

Instead of: `http://*.*.*.*/intranet/migration/intranet/files/s1_2015_-_iworld_release_6.12.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

If you currently have `src="/files/..."` and you want to have `src="/migration/intranet/files/..."` you should do a search and replace like this

```
UPDATE field_data_body SET body_value = REPLACE( body_value, '<a href=\"/files/', '<a href=\"/migration/intranet/files/') WHERE entity_id = 20916;
```