# MySql - Way to update portion of a string with part of another string?

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way to replace just a portion of a string with a part of a string for same row via MySQL query.

For example, if I have records that title='blablabla - XX.YY.ZZZZ' and I want to add only the string, ZZZZ, to a field - extra_fields but with a format '[{"value":"ZZZZ"}]'

Original table:

```
title | extra_field
--------------------
19.02.1996 | [empty]
13.05.1815 | [empty]
22.03.2016 | [empty]
```

After the update I need:

```
title | extra_field
-------------------
19.02.1996 | Year was 1996 
13.05.1815 | Year was 1815 
22.03.2016 | Year was 2016
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956993/mysql-string-replace

Comment: not quite. I need a way to extract only ZZZZ part so it can be replaced

Comment: UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, 'ZZZZ', '[{"value":"ZZZZ"}]')
WHERE your_field LIKE 'ZZZZ'

Comment: @Aroniaina I updated original post with visuals

Comment: now, it is clear, remember to be clear if you ask a question

Comment: UPDATE yourtable SET extra_field = CONCAT('Year was ', SUBSTRING(title,7))

Comment: Just as a warning: if that is actually all you want to do: do not do it! It will duplicate your data (you will have the information "1996" twice in your row, and the text "Year was" in every row) That will have the effect that, when you later change "title" (or "extra_field"), the values get out of sync; and if you want to use the text "The year was", you have to update every row. Do that in the query, e.g. `select title, CONCAT('Year was ', SUBSTRING(title,7)) as extra_field from...` (or in php). If you just update some specific rows (or if it was just an example), this might not be relevant.

Comment: @Aroniaina You saved my life! I used UPDATE yourtable SET extra_field = CONCAT('Year was ', SUBSTRING(title,-4)) so it wont matter all the garbage that is written before.

Answer (score 0):

The query solution

```
UPDATE yourtable SET extra_field = CONCAT('Year was ', SUBSTRING(title,7))
```

**OR**

```
UPDATE yourtable SET extra_field = CONCAT('Year was ', SUBSTRING(title,-4))
```