# How can I format my sql with slashs?

Tags: mysql, sql, formatting, slash

```
SELECT PATH AS STRUCTURE
FROM OBJ_RESOURCE  
WHERE PATH LIKE '%Small Business%'
```

**STRUCTURE**

> \Small Business\Organisation / IT / Logistik\Organisation /Governance\Person\Prozess-User

I get above data but i need the second one only with slashs:

**STRUCTURE**

> /Small Business/Organisation / IT / Logistik/Organisation / Governance/Person/Prozess-User

Comment: So you need to replace normal slash by backslash in the output of your SQL query?

Comment: I need to replace backslash with slash in my query I tried already but it dont work

Comment: `SELECT REPLACE(PATH, '\', '/') AS STRUCTURE` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956993/mysql-string-replace#answer-5957021

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL string replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956993/mysql-string-replace)

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  Use replace function. Replace forward slash first then replace 2x backslash with one backslash.  See demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/be5b0/14

```
SELECT  REPLACE(REPLACE(PATH, '/', '\'), '\\','/')  AS STRUCTURE 
from OBJ_RESOURCE;

Result: /Small Business/Organisation / IT / Logistik/Organisation /Governance/Person/Prozess-User
```

=======

The problem is when you insert the data into the table, there are missing backslash. See sample below:

```
create table OBJ_RESOURCE (path varchar(100));
insert into OBJ_RESOURCE values('\\Small Business\\Organisation \/ IT \/ Logistik\\Organisation \/Governance\\Person\\Prozess-User');
```

Comment: i only need slash no backslash

Comment: you put in your post that you want the first STRUCTURE data: \Small Business\Organisation / IT / Logistik\Organisation /Governance\Person\Prozess-User.  Please tell us what data you want to see.

Comment: /Small Business/Organisation / IT / Logistik/Organisation / Governance/Person/Prozess-User only with slash

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ, anna wants slashes, not backslahes. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7beb8/3