# How to replace a mySQL column that contains specific text?

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I have the table "behavior" and a column "url".
The column "url" contains some rows as below.

What I want to do is to change the rows of column "url" such as

```
/this-is/the-main-url?fbclid=IwAR1VIvXLBSIs4S_eRc4FGVYhIsiViWPEBBSmpkHMatjAcH0Rh-_u4VGoo
```

to

```
/this-is/the-main-url
```

and likewise this

```
/here-is/another-url?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=fb.traffic
```

to

```
/here-is/another-url
```

of the behavior table.

So, if the string contains `?fbclid` 
or `?utm_source` to keep everything before it.

This can be done also by using multiple queries, instead of one complex.

**NOTE:**
The utm_source or fbclid, parameters and ids can be various, so I need a dynamic solution.

Thank you

Comment: REPLACE with REGEXP maybe?

Comment: did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956993/mysql-string-replace

Comment: @Kurohige the "base" url is not the same, but different. the example in your link is the same.

Comment: how does this question relates to `mysql, sql, mysqli`?

Comment: @Alex I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

MySQL `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function is convenient.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Demonstration

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           t.foo 
           ,'?fbclid'
           ,1
         )
         ,'?utm_source'
         ,1
       )
  FROM ( SELECT '/this-is/the-main-url?fbclid=IwAR1VIvXLBSIs4S_eRc4FGVYhIsiViWPEBBSmpkHMatjAcH0Rh-_u4VGoo' AS foo 
         UNION ALL SELECT '/here-is/another-url?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=fb.traffic'
       ) t
```

---

Once we have expression working and tested, we can make use of those expressions in an `UPDATE` statement. But we want to test the expressions in a `SELECT` statement first.

```
 UPDATE mytable 
    SET mycol = SUBSTRING_INDEX( mycol ,'?fbclid',1)
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

The specification in the original question was to remove strings `'?fbclid'` and `?utm_source` from string.

The question is now updated to say "parameters and ids can be various, so I need a dynamic solution."

If we just want to chop everything after (and including) the first question mark character, then we can do this:

```
  SUBSTRING_INDEX( myurl ,'?',1)
```

If we want to leave some question mark characters, and only trim off certain strings, then we can invoke `SUBSTRING_INDEX` multiple times.

As far as making this more dynamic, we can make a call to `SUBSTRING_INDEX` for each delimiter, and pass in the delimiter argument (the second argument) to `SUBSTRING_INDEX` as a parameter.

Comment: Hi, I made some updates into my question, needing a more dynamic approach.

Answer (score 0):

this will work indeed:

```
select substring(colname,1,instr(colname,'?')-1) from tablename;
```

to change column as a whole :

```
update tablename set colname=
select substring(colname,1,instr(colname,'?')-1) from tablename;
```