# Deleting part of a string that is saved in MySQL field

Tags: php, mysql

I have done my research on the subject and I thought about using replace, but the trouble is if I replaced with nothing, then I will end up with lots of spaces in my database field which will get very messy. So I have come to you guys for help.

I have a field in my database called EQUIPMENT. This is an example of what is in one of the fields

15<>5<>6<>3<>2<>1<>14<>13<>12

Each number is representing the ID of a piece of equipment. How would I go about deleting for example <>6
 As I said, I looked at using replace but replacing it with ' ' would leave spaces in the field.

Comment: use the db REPLACE(column, string_to_find, replace_with) function, but also, please get into the habit of "ALWAYS' using a WHERE clause that uses... WHERE column LIKE(%string_to_find%), so the REPLACE() only happens when string_to_find is actually in column you want to run the REPLACE() on!

Answer (score 0):

Replace with '' (no space) should not leave a space. You could also use trim, if you don't want any whitespaces.

Comment: mysql_query(UPDATE `Drug_Factory` SET `EQUIPMENT`= REPLACE(EQUIPMENT, '<>6', '') WHERE `ID`='$factory_2_id' ")
                  or die(" connect to database failled!");

Comment: This should work shouldn't it? It is just causing my code not to run though.

Comment: The query itself looks correct and should work. Maybe something else that is wrong, ex. some simple syntax error? Could try to echo out the query and see if it looks correct and try to run it directly in a db client.

Comment: Missing a " right at the beginning, what an idiot! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure if this is what you want, but before inserting value just use:

`echo str_replace("<>", "", "15<>5<>6<>3<>2<>1<>14<>13<>12");`

Output: `1556321141312`

To delete `<>6` use `echo str_replace("<>6", "", "15<>5<>6<>3<>2<>1<>14<>13<>12");`

Outcome: `15<>5<>3<>2<>1<>14<>13<>12`

If you want to do this on mysql database then this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14586441/5459942

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing a "<>number" by an empty string, you can replace a "<>number<>" by "<>".
This is to avoid that other numbers (that contain that number) are also replaced partially.

And to avoid a wrong result when the number is at the start or the end of the string,  a '<>' is concatinated to both ends.

Then those '<>' at both ends can be trimmed after the replace.

**Example:**

```
select 
 EQUIPMENT,
 TRIM(BOTH '<>' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT('<>',EQUIPMENT,'<>'),CONCAT('<>',6,'<>'),'<>')) as Equipment_without_6
from
(
 select '15<>5<>6<>3<>2<>1<>14<>13<>12' as EQUIPMENT
 union all select '6<>16<>6<>60<>6'
) q
```

**Returns:**

```
EQUIPMENT                      Equipment_without_6
------------------------------ ---------------------------
15<>5<>6<>3<>2<>1<>14<>13<>12  15<>5<>3<>2<>1<>14<>13<>12
6<>16<>6<>60<>6                16<>60
```

Comment: I got past that issue kind of but now my issue has moved on to soomething else. This is what is in the field I am changing 15<>5<>6<>3<>2<>1<>14<>13<>12

Comment: mysql_query(UPDATE Drug_Factory SET EQUIPMENT= REPLACE(EQUIPMENT, '<>1', '') WHERE ID='$factory_2_id' ") or die(" connect to database failled!"); This is the code I am using, it is deleting the <>1 on it is own but it is also deleting the 1 in the <>14 leaving it as <>4 is there any way to only replace exact matches

Comment: If you take a closer look at the answer you'll notice it replaces not '<>6' by '', but '<>6<>' by '<>'.  It's to avoid stuff like also changing other numbers that have a 6.