# Replace last characters of a STRING column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all, I am a newbie in SQL, and I cannot realize how to solve this simple problem.

I have a table like this:

```
ID    NAME    PATH
----------------------------
1     Peter   img_peter.png
2     Jon     img_jon.png
3     Maria   img_maria.png
```

I want to modify the column `PATH` in order to replace the extension `.png` to `.jpg`.

Therefore, the output UPDATE should return:

```
ID    NAME    PATH
----------------------------
1     Peter   img_peter.jpg
2     Jon     img_jon.jpg
3     Maria   img_maria.jpg
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL string replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956993/mysql-string-replace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `replace()` for this:

```
update t
    set path = replace(path, '.png', '.jpg')
    where path like '%.png';
```

This assumes that `.png` does not occur multiple times in the string, but that seems like a reasonable assumption.