# How to cut part of a string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

In MySQL, I have a text column with "bla bla bla YYY=76767 bla bla bla".

I need to cut the number 76767.

How can I do it in SQL?

Comment: what would the output string `bla bla bla YYY= bla bla bla`??

Comment: Do you want to remove the number, or to fetch it ?

Comment: Do you wish to update the actual data to take out the "76767" from the value?

Comment: Update instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876762/mysql-way-to-update-portion-of-a-string || regex replace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
select substring_index(substring(mycol, instr(mycol, "=")+1), " ", 1)
```

to get the first token after the `=`.

This returns  `76767`.

---

This works in two steps :

```
substring(mycol, instr(mycol, "=")+1)
```

returns the string starting after the `=`

and

```
substring_index( xxx , " ", 1)
```

get the first element of the virtual array you'd got from a split by " ", and so returns the first token of xxx.

Comment: More abstract/general: set `@frst` and `@scnd` as delimiters. The term you are looking for is between `@frst` and `@scnd`. In this case it is `SET @frst:='YYY='; SET @scnd:='';` You either want to update, so then `UPDATE tbl set my_col = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(my_col , INSTR(my_col , @frst)+1), @scnd, 1) WHERE my_col LIKE '%@scnd%';` or you want to select, so `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(my_col , INSTR(my_col , @frst)+1), @scnd, 1) from WHERE my_col LIKE '%@scnd%';`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach to eliminate the number in your field would be just to [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) it.

```
SELECT REPLACE(yourcolumn, '76767', '')
FROM yourtable;
```

You can use a combination of [`SUBSTRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) and [`INSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_instr), too.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to UPDATE, use

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, '76767', '');
```

If you wan't to replace `76767` with `bla bla bla` in your db, use

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, '76767', 'bla bla bla');
```