# SQL to remove partial text from value

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I write the SQL to remove some text from the value of records if it exists.

```
Version Column data
 ------------------  
WEB 1.0.1  
WEB 1.0.1  
1.0.2  
1.0.2
```

I would like to update all records that contain "WEB " and remove that text but leave the rest, "1.0.1".

So far I  have `Select * from table`.

Database is MySQL 5.5.25

Comment: With what RDMBS are you working?

Comment: May you just look at string functions for you RDMBS?

Comment: @Kostia, RTFM comments are not welcome.  @1.21 gigawatts - You might also be interested in using `REPLACE` to update records as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876762/mysql-way-to-update-portion-of-a-string

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `REPLACE` feature of **MySQL**, **SQL Server**, and **PostGres** will remove all occurrences of `WEB` with a blank.

**Selecting**

```
SELECT REPLACE(Version, 'WEB ', '') FROM MyTable
```

**Updating**

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Version = REPLACE(Version, 'WEB ', '')
```

or

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Version = REPLACE(Version, 'WEB ', '') WHERE Version LIKE '%WEB %'
```

**Reference**

- [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) - SQL Server
- [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) - MySQL
- [REPLACE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) - PostGres
- I included multiple DB Servers in the answer as well as selecting and updating due several edits to the question

Comment: OK. I created a row with the value in the field is "TEST 1.0.1". I tested with REPLACE(version, 'TEST ', '') and it said it affected 9000 rows but it doesn't seem to have changed anything. (refreshed the table)

Comment: Your question was about `SELECTING` rows, if you want to `UPDATE` rows, it is different. I will edit my answer to show the difference.

Answer (score 1):

In postgres this would be:

```
select substring(Version from 5 for 3) 
from table
where Version like '%WEB%'
```

Comment: same function exists for postgres

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table
SET Version = Replace(Version, 'Web ','')
WHERE Version LIKE 'WEB %'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example that should work in any SQL as functions used are ANSI SQL standard. This example assumes that there is a whitespace between word 'WEB' and first digit. But it can be improved. I think this is more generic approach then hardcoding start and end positions for subtr:

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTR('WEB 1.0.1', INSTR('WEB 1.0.1', ' ') ) ) as version 
  FROM dual;

 SQL> 

 VERSION
 -------
 1.0.1
```