# Update a word in full name in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I need to update only one word in ful name .For exp. I have a name
`"Abc Cde LEF PQr"`.I want to replace `Abc with Thg.`
I have used query to find names which contains `Abc`

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%Abc%'
```

Please help me to do next step to replace the word

Comment: So its always the first word you want to replace ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876762/mysql-way-to-update-portion-of-a-string

Comment: And just for future reference, if you googled `mysql replace` the first and second links would have sent you to the functions linked below by most of those who answered. I'm just saying that there was a little more room to try on your own before you asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
UPDATE table  SET column = REPLACE(column, 'abc', 'thg');
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET name = REPLACE(name, 'Abc', 'Thg')
WHERE `name` LIKE '%Abc%'
```

Reference:

- [REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace into the select query, it's not destructive for database data. Try :

```
SELECT
  REPLACE(field1, 'Abc', 'Thg')
FROM table
WHERE name LIKE '%Abc%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Replace Function**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php)

Try this

```
UPDATE table  SET name = REPLACE(name, 'abc', 'thg');
WHERE name LIKE '%Abc%'
```