# Updating/changing a specific portion of a string in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have tried a couple different approaches to doing this, and all seem to return an error. So in this exact situation, I'm trying to replace something in garrysmod with another. In this case, it's a playermodel. And I'm using the mysql pointshop. I want to replace specifically in the items row only the word "ironman" with "vector". Here are the different ones I have tried:

```
UPDATE `pointshop_data` SET `items` = REPLACE(`items`, 'ironman', 'vector')
```

and

```
UPDATE pointshop_data SET items = REPLACE(items, 'ironman', 'vector') WHERE items LIKE '%ironman%';
```

Both of which came from here: [MySql - Way to update portion of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876762/mysql-way-to-update-portion-of-a-string)

Any different approaches I've tried I get the same syntax error: http://gyazo.com/03a6774b2d78956a8c5b41c588e9c568

I feel like I'm missing the smallest step here, but I did exactly as the answers stated in the other question.

Comment: Are you using the same query which you have mentioned? As your query looks good to me.

Comment: Yes, and I've tried other ones that are variations of the two you see above. All seem to return the same error shown in that screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

try following query:

```
UPDATE 'pointshop_data' SET items = REPLACE(items, 'ironman', 'vector') WHERE items LIKE '%ironman%';
```

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed in my second piece of code I forgot to put items where field should be. I already tried this one with items in place, I just forgot to fix it when creating this question. Unfortunately this query gives the same error.

Comment: @Jerpy which version of MySQL you are using?

Comment: Still get the same error. I'm using the mysql version of the pointshop data provider.

Comment: @Jerpy i think you will not be able to use update query directly in pointshop and may be you have to use any Function of pointshop no idea about that. some one with experience of working on pointshop can help you