# Remove an attribute from all the img src tags in MySQL (Wordpress installation)

Tags: html, mysql, wordpress

My Wordpress site has several hundred images that have the following attribute:

`rel="lightbox" or rel=lightbox`

So, my img src looks like this:
`<img src="/image1.png" rel="lightbox">` or `<img src="/image1.png" rel=lightbox>`

There must be more than 2000 images on my site and I'm pretty sure that nearly 500-600 of such images will have rel="lightbox" or rel=lightbox attributes.

Mine is MySQL database.

How do I remove the rel="lightbox" or rel=lightboxes from all these 500-600 images?

Comment: Are the `rel="lightbox"` attributes *only* on `img` tags?  Can we assume we can remove them all, regardless of tag?  If this is WordPress, can we assume you're only talking about updating the `wp_posts.post_content` field?

Comment: Yes.. I believe the rel="lightbox" is only inside the '<img src>' tags..

Comment: I am ok at MySQL or just SQL commands.  However, WordPress is written in PHP. It should be fairly simple to just make a one-time function in PHP that selects all records with the word "lightbox" in it and then use PHP's string manipulation code to remove the entire "rel='lightbox'" portion using a preg_replace() command and then just update the record.

Comment: I just did a search - look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876762/mysql-way-to-update-portion-of-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Go to where your code print these images or you can do it in header or body section prefereably:
You can catch those by using some php code:

```
<?php foreach ($imgs as $img) { ?>
<?php
if($img['rel'] != "lightbox")
{ ?>
```

you can do what ever you want the url to print.
        somthing like this img src with url and without rel attribute

```
<img src="<?php echo $img['rel']; ?>"  />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of "How do I REMOVE it from the record?"  See my second posting above.

Comment: so you are telling me that lightbox exist in database table.you want it to delete from there.suppose it exist there you delete it from there then when code will call img src rel attribute then it would be like this rel="".

Comment: inn: I am supposing you are talking to me. :-) The original question was simply how to remove the "rel='lightbox'" or "rel=lightbox" part of the string. Ravichopra does not say or ask how to put this in to his HTML or what to do about it. Your answer is assuming Ravichopra wants to KEEP the option and how to block it.  Not the same thing. Thus, your answer does not answer the original question.  Not that your answer is a bad answer.  Far from it. But it is not the answer this person was looking for. Ok? :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Back up your database**, then run the following SQL:

```
update wp_posts
set post_content = replace(post_content, ' rel="lightbox"', '')
where post_content like '% rel="lightbox"%';

update wp_posts
set post_content = replace(post_content, ' rel=lightbox', '')
where post_content like '% rel=lightbox%';
```

assuming it's just the `post_content` field you're talking about, and that you have the default db prefix (`wp_`).